# Getting error: package androidx.viewbinding does not exist error

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

I am working in an application where I am using reference of ViewBinding but it gives package androidx.viewbinding does not exist error.In the below code I am passing Generic viewbinding.It works on Android studio 4.13 but does not work on Android studio 3.52
Please tell me if there is any work around for this

```
     return new BaseAdapter<Contact, ViewBinding>(this, 
        getmViewModel().getContacts().getValue()) {
        private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
        @Override
        public int getAdapterLayoutResId(int viewType) {
            if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) { return R.layout.item_contact; }
            else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) { return R.layout.item_loading; }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindData(Contact model, int position, ViewBinding dataBinding) {
            if (dataBinding instanceof ItemContactBinding) {
                ((ItemContactBinding) dataBinding).setContact(model);
                ((ItemContactBinding) dataBinding).setPosition(position);
                ((ItemContactBinding) dataBinding).setListener((ContactIdSelectionListener) getContext());
            }
            else if(dataBinding instanceof ItemLoadingBinding) {
                ((ItemLoadingBinding) dataBinding).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true); }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Contact model, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemType(int position) {
            return getItem(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you sure those versions are 4.13, 3.52, and not 4.1.3 and 3.5.2? Also, can you update how you are adding view binding support in build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

In the versions prior to *4.0* view binding support was added (in app-level `build.gradle`) using

```
android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

and it changed in Android studio *4.0* and higher to

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

That is why your Android Studio *v3.5.2* can not generate `ViewBinding` files.